# SQL to Select only full groups of data

Tags: sql

Let's say I have three sample tables for groups of people as shown below.

Table **users**:

| id | name | available |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | true |
| 2 | Nick | true |
| 3 | Sam | false |

Table **groups**:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | study |
| 2 | games |

Table **group_users**:

| group_id | user_id | role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | teach |
| 1 | 2 | stdnt |
| 1 | 3 | stdnt |
| 2 | 1 | tank |
| 2 | 2 | heal |

And I need to show to a user all groups that he participates in and also available right now, which means all users in that group have `users.available = true`.

I tried something like:

```
SELECT `groups`.*, `users`.* , `group_users`.*
FROM `groups` 
LEFT JOIN `group_users` ON `groups`.`id` = `group_users`.`group_id` 
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `group_users`.`user_id` 
WHERE `users`.`available` = true AND `users`.`id` = 1
```

But it just shows groups and part of their users, that are available. And I need to have ONLY the groups that have all their users available.

If I were to find all available groups as User 1 - I should get only group 2 and it's users. How to do this the right way?

---

**Tables DDL**:

```
CREATE TABLE users ( 
    id        int          PRIMARY KEY, 
    name      varchar(256) NOT NULL, 
    available bool 
); 
CREATE TABLE teams ( 
    id        int          PRIMARY KEY, 
    name      varchar(256) NOT NULL 
); 
CREATE TABLE team_users ( 
    team_id   int          NOT NULL, 
    user_id   int          NOT NULL, 
    role      varchar(64) 
); 

INSERT INTO users VALUES 
(1, 'John', true ), 
(2, 'Nick', true ), 
(3, 'Sam' , false); 
INSERT INTO teams VALUES 
(1, 'study'), 
(2, 'games'); 
INSERT INTO team_users VALUES 
(1, 1, 'teach'),
(1, 2, 'stdnt'),
(1, 3, 'stdnt'),
(2, 1, 'tank' ),
(2, 2, 'heal' );
```

mySQL select version() output:

```
10.8.3-MariaDB-1:10.8.3+maria~jammy
```

Comment: provide your structures as CREATE TABLE. Add some sample data as INSERT INTO. Show desired output for shown data (or 2-3 outputs for different selected users). Also specify precise MySQL version (show output for `select version();`).

Comment: *And I need to have ONLY the groups that have all their users available.* Does when the user itself is not available then the output must be empty? or the user itself availability should be ignored?

Comment: mySQL version - 10.8.3

Comment: I need to have only fully-available groups, if user is unavailable - he should get empty output)

Comment: Please insert the code into the question text as an update. `mySQL version - 10.8.3` ?? actual version is 8.0.30 yet... check the version carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Check do you need in this:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT users.name username, 
           teams.id teamid,
           teams.name teamname,
           SUM(NOT users.available) OVER (PARTITION BY teams.id) non_availabe_present,
           SUM(users.name = @user_name) OVER (PARTITION BY teams.id) needed_user_present
    FROM team_users
    JOIN users ON team_users.user_id = users.id
    JOIN teams ON team_users.team_id = teams.id
)
SELECT username, teamid, teamname
FROM cte
WHERE needed_user_present
  AND NOT non_availabe_present;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=605cf10d147fd904fb2d4a6cd5968302

PS. I use user name as a criteria, you may edit and use user's identifier, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Join the tables and aggregate with the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name
FROM teams t
INNER JOIN team_users tu ON t.id = tu.team_id  
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = tu.user_id 
GROUP BY t.id
HAVING MIN(u.available) AND SUM(u.id = 1);
```

The `HAVING` clause is a simplification of:

```
HAVING MIN(u.available) = true AND SUM(u.id = 1) > 0
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=be19674fb9253033ff9663ea9d2b5563).

Answer (score 0):

first you need to find those group which users is available. then find the all the group details of those group which is not related to those group which user is available.

```
SELECT * FROM team_users a
JOIN teams b ON a.team_id=b.id
JOIN users c ON a.user_id=c.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1 FROM team_users tu
    JOIN users u ON tu.user_id=u.id AND u.available =1
    WHERE tu.team_id=a.Team_id
)
```